# How to correcting create a request callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm failing to understand how to correctly await for `request` function to complete. I usually have no problem with callbacks but certainly am not as experienced as I'd like to be. I can't wrap my head around this one. I'm wanting to call `console.log('print afterwards')` after everything in the `x()` function is complete. But the request block is skipped and only entered after everything else is called. Apologies for my inexperience.

```
1  const request = require("request");
2  const cheerio = require("cheerio");
3
4  let x = function() {
5
6      request(URL, (error, response, html) => {
7
8          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
9              const $ = cheerio.load(html);
10             console.log(html)
11          }
12      });
13   }
14 
15  function main() {
16     x()
17     console.log('print afterwards')
18  }
19
20  main()
```

This is the order everything is called during debugging.

```
1   const request = require("request");
2   const cheerio = require("cheerio");
4   let x = function() {
20  main()
16  x()
6   request(URL, (error, response, html) => {
13  }
17  console.log('print afterwards')
18  }
8   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
9   const $ = cheerio.load(html);
10  console.log(html)
12  });
```

This is the desired order.

```
1   const request = require("request");
2   const cheerio = require("cheerio");
4   let x = function() {
20  main()
16  x()
6   request(URL, (error, response, html) => {
8   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
9   const $ = cheerio.load(html);
10  console.log(html)
12  });
13  }
17  console.log('print afterwards')
18  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because it's a promise object, so it's technically returning a `promise object` instead of the data, which comes later. It's asynchronous. Run a `console.log(typeof object)` where the object is what you're trying to get returned. My guess is it's a promise.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it's an object. Interesting I don't understand how i'd approach this? So it's not a function. It's an object that is called then when everything else in the thread is called the contents of the object are executed?

Comment: It's not a promise.  The `request()` library doesn't use promises.  There is no way to "wait" for it to be done.  Instead, you continue your code inside the callback - that's where you know it's done.  It is non-blocking and asynchronous so it returns as soon as it has started the operation.  Also, the `request()` library has been deprecated.  You should pick [one of the alternatives](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) that do use promises like [got()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).  Then, you could use `await` to sequence things a bit more naturally.

Comment: Node-fetch seems to be a good alternative. Does it not use promises? The reason why I'm needing a callback is i'm trying to export the task as a module that needs to be awaited. So I can't really continue the code inside the callback. At least I don't believe so.

Comment: I didn't see the Node tag. Yeah - Node is *definitely* not async. It's a callback nightmare (IMO). If you get into async, I'd recommend Deno, as an aside. :)

Comment: Hahah okay noted, i'll avoid it. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: use axios => Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js. https://github.com/axios/axios =>  is very popular

Comment: I remember hearing about axios. Haven't checked it out until now. Looks good, thanks again

Comment: and see this answer for using callback function in request => https://stackoverflow.com/a/42220616/9681220, maybe help you

Comment: Well, as of 2020, you can't export something that is obtained asynchronously.  Can't do it.  That feature is being worked on for some future date, but not something you can do now.  Even if you used a request library that uses promises and use `await` with it, it won't help you export an asynchronously retrieved value.

Comment: @JoelHager - node.js is completely asynchronous.  It's I/O is asynchronous.  So, you're just completely wrong on that account.  Deno is an interesting environment, but it's really, really early for that (doesn't even really have complete documentation yet) and there's zero reason this question needs or benefits uniquely from Deno.  This is just like thousands of other node.js questions here as newbies learn how to program with asynchronous I/O.  First thing to do is to get rid of the `request()` library and use something based on promises like `got()` or `node-fetch()` or `axios()`.

Comment: I should rephrase. It uses callbacks over promises, which are natively asynchronous...

Comment: Stuck between got and axios. What would you recommend?

Comment: @srb633 see this link: https://npmcompare.com/compare/axios,got,request,reqwest,superagent - and this link: https://medium.com/@jeffrey.allen.lewis/http-requests-compared-why-axios-is-better-than-node-fetch-more-secure-can-handle-errors-better-39fde869a4a6